# Relativity and magnetic force

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Relativity states that you cannot measure your own speed when there is no frame of reference. Imagine an indefinitely large area of uniform magnetic field and a charged particle moving through it. The particle will experience a force $F=qvB$. Since force does not comply to the rule of relativity (because you can measure forces without a frame of reference), one can deduce the particle's speed. Where is the fault in the logic here?

Comment: The velocity $\mathbf{v}$ you put in the expression of Lorentz's force is the velocity w.r.t. an observer, or a reference frame. And even when you interpret the effects of the EM field only as the effects of $\mathbf{B}$, you're implicitly assuming you're in a reference frame

Comment: @basics so, without concerning any frames of reference, would I be able to measure the force on the particle?

Comment: Physics should be independent from the coordinates you use to describe it (moreover equations have the same expression if written in two inertial reference frames). Anyway, when you perform an experiment, I think that you can interpret your lab as a reference frame, so that you can measure velocities w.r.t. you and interpret the EM fields as a magnetic field only, an electric field only, or a combination of them. If I'm moving w.r.t. you in a inertial reference frame w.r.t. yours, I'd measure the same force, while measuring a different velocity and seeing different contributions to EM field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $F = q v B$ gives the force on a charge $q$ travelling at speed $v$ *with respect to a reference frame* due to a magnetic field $B$ *in that reference frame* (assuming $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are perpendicular). If we wish to consider a reference frame in which the charge is at rest, we can do a Lorentz transformation (a boost of $u = v$ in the direction of the charge's motion). It turns out that this introduces an electric field $E = v B$ (in the limit where $v \ll c$) in the new frame, which produces the same force as $B$ in the original frame. Essentially, the choice of reference frames will determine the electric and magnetic fields observed. However, provided they differ by $u \ll c$, the resulting electromagnetic (Lorentz) forces will be the same.

For $u$ comparable with $c$, force will not be consistent between reference frames. Rather, forces in different frames will be related via Lorentz transformations as part of the four force.

Comment: ah I see, so my measurement of B already implies a frame of reference. Clear, concise answer, thanks!